# JAVA - Leer los atributos de un nodo XML

Tags: java, xml, xpath, documentbuilder

Estoy intentado leer las líneas de un fichero XML utilizando la librería XPath. Hasta el momento he conseguido leer cada uno de los nodos del documento que estoy procesando pero no sé como acceder a un atributo concreto del nodo.

Para que se entienda mejor pondré un ejemplo junto con el código que tengo desarrollado hasta el momento:

```
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
<string key1="/path" key2="title" key3="English" value="Spanish"/>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es obtener el valor del atributo `value` que en el ejemplo todos los nodos contienen el texto "Spanish".

Con el siguiente código leo cada una de las líneas peo no sé cómo acceder al valor de los atributos con la libreria XPath de Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        String xPathExpression = "//string";

        Document documento = null;
        NodeList nodos = null;

        try {
            // Carga del documento xml
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            documento = builder.parse(new File("./src/TestResults/xmlFile.lang"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            // Preparación de xpath
            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            // Consultas
            nodos = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xPathExpression, documento, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        for (int i=0;i<nodos.getLength();i++){
            System.out.println("********* ITER " + i + " *********");
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getNodeName());
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getNodeValue());
            System.out.println(nodos.item(i).getAttributes());
            System.out.println("**************************");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

probablemente sea porque la ruta del `XPath` que estas declarando no esta bien definida, te dejo el código con diferente estructura si no es de molestia, es mejor siempre declararse métodos para que sea mas entendible el código.

```
public class PruebaString {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc = null;

    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    doc = builder.parse("./src/TestResults/xmlFile.lang");

    // Creamos Objeto XPathFactory
    XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

    // Creamos Objeto XPath
    XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

    // Llamas al método
    ExtraerAtributoValue(doc, xpath);

}

private static void ExtraerAtributoValue(Document doc, XPath xpath) {
    try {

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[local-name() = 'string']/@value");
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int v1 = 0; v1 < nodes.getLength(); v1++) {
            Node prueba = nodes.item(v1);
            String value = prueba.getTextContent();

            System.out.println("Value: " + value);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.